# Radius corners of views in xml

Tags: android, xml

I have an Android calculator app that I'm working on and I want to make the text view corners radius and there is two text views I want to appear to be one so I need to only round 2 corners on the outside edge of the views. Here is my main.xml

```
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/question"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|right"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="0 + 0"
        android:textColor="#ff333333"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/answer"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="2dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="= ?"
        android:textColor="#ff333333"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/clear"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="@drawable/enter_back"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:text="C"
        android:textColor="#ff333333"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by adding 3 new android xml files to your drawable folder then setting them as background in your main.xml file. to the right views

android:background="@drawable/answer_back"  to the main.xml view @ id="@+id/answer"
answer_back.xml to radius the right side corners:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:dither="true" >    
     <gradient
          android:angle="90"
          android:endColor="#ffffffff"
          android:startColor="#ff99ffcc" />

     <corners 
          android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
          android:topRightRadius="20dp"/>
 </shape>
```

android:background="@drawable/question_back" to the main.xml view @ id="@+id/question"
question_back.xml to radius the left side corners:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:dither="true" >    
    <gradient
          android:angle="90"
          android:endColor="#ffffffff"
          android:startColor="#ff99ffcc" />

    <corners 
          android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
          android:topLeftRadius="20dp"/>
 </shape>
```

android:background="@drawable/num_back" to the main.xml view @ all the button views
num_back.xml to set the radius of all corners

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:dither="true" >    
    <gradient
          android:angle="90"
          android:endColor="#ffffffff"
          android:startColor="#ff99ffcc" />

    <corners<corners android:radius="20dp" />
 </shape>
```